# How to set network proxy for install4j "download jre" service

Tags: proxy, install4j

In the install4j Windows Edition 6.1.5 (build 6349) IDE running on Windows 7 Enterprise, I need to use the "Download JREs" utility to retrieve a JRE bundle. The download step fails, probably because the network proxy must be defined.  The documentation shows a "Connection Settings" step of this utility, but that step is missing when I run "Download JREs".

So how do I set the proxy for the install4j IDE?  I've searched the documentation and application settings and can find instructions on how to set the proxy for installers generated by the IDE, but not for the IDE itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `bin/install4j.vmoptions` and define the properties:

```
-DproxySet=true
-DproxyHost=...
-DproxyPort=...
```

If you need to authenticate, then also add the properties:

```
-DproxyAuth=true
-DproxyAuthUser=...
```

Comment: This is a step towards the solution (thanks).  But it turns out that the corporate internet filter is blocking access to the download site.  And install4j support says that they no longer host the specific file that I was trying to download.

So I ended up creating a new JRE bundle via the install4j IDE's "Create JRE Bundle" function.